# Email reports via SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have SQL Server Reporting Services running on SQL Server 2008 R2 and we've created some subscriptions to email to specific people. My question is: can I query a database and use an email address from the database to automatically email the report based on that email address in the database?

Comment: So I see data-driven subscriptions. I presume that is the answer? Is that only available in the enterprise version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sql Server Agent if you trying to send data automatically Time base

and 
You can use this code with modified according to Your Requirnment

```
declare @id int
declare @name varchar(25)
declare @age int
declare @exp datetime
declare @msgbody varchar(100)

declare @add varchar(max)
declare cursername cursor

for 

select id,name,age, convert(varchar(10),exprire,103)as exprire from Tablename 

open cursername
fetch next from cursername into  @id ,@name,@age,@exp



while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

begin
fetch next from cursername
into @id ,@name,@age,@exp

set @msgbody = ''+ CAST(@id as varchar(20))+ '    '+ @name +'    '+  CAST(@age as varchar(20))  +'    '+ CONVERT(varchar(20),@exp,103) +''
set @add = @add + @msgbody



print ''+ CAST(@id as varchar(20)) + @name +  CAST(@age as varchar(20))  + CONVERT(varchar(20),@exp,103) +''
end 


use msdb
EXEC sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name='dv', 
@recipients='Emailreciever@yahoo.com', 
@subject='Send data specific',
@body=   @add

close cursername
deallocate cursername
```

I hope it is useful to Your